# Why do I get a "seam" using Mirror modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I started using Blender a few weeks ago and right now I'm starting my first project without a tutorial. I'm starting to create a character and the first thing that came to my mind was "It needs to have symmetry", so I used a Mirror modifier on my object and it has this "seam". In the image I used a Sphere because it is much more noticeable.

So, how can I fix it? And why does this happens?

[image: Here's the sphere with the "seam"]

Comment: You probably forgot to include the image you referred to. But try checking `Clip` in the mirror modifier's settings, to 'prevent vertices from moving through the mirror plane' (https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html#options).

Answer (score 2):

You should turn on clipping, as Cebbi has already mentioned. Also, the subsurf modifier should go after the mirror modifier.

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was the order of the modifiers. It tried a lot of things,  yet I forgot about the most simple.

PD: I'm DarkDiosito, the one that helpled was Cebbi. THANKS CEBBI!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: you could mark this as answered. ;)