# Is there any way to clean the joints created by mirror modifier?

Tags: bezier-curves, edges, mirror

[image]

Hi Guys, I created the above bottle using the mirror modifier but when I am smoothing it, it leaves the edges/vertices joint, as I shown using red arrows. Please suggest how can I remove this visible separation line?

Comment: Hard to see the cause here: an angle or a non joint vertices?

Comment: Try changing the modifiers order using the arrows near their names. I think the mirror modifier needs to be on top of the smooth modifier.

Comment: I believe this is a limitation of the viewport - if you do a render (or preview render) you should see that it is smooth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subsurf and mirror modifier creating a split in mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/subsurf-and-mirror-modifier-creating-a-split-in-mesh) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69020/why-do-i-get-a-seam-using-mirror-modifier