# Wierd line when using Mirror

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces, mirror, subdivision-surface

Does anyone know how to fix this wierd line?(I'm new to blender btw)

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69020/why-do-i-get-a-seam-using-mirror-modifier and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/subsurf-and-mirror-modifier-creating-a-split-in-mesh

Comment: Placing mirror modifier at the top will prevent this from happening.  Also, this effect can be a contribution of 'auto-smooth' setting with a low angle threshold setting.